# date_add() changing 2 variables in PHP rather than 1

Tags: php, dateadd

Here is an example of the code I used:

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
$date1 = date_create("2014-04-05");
$date2 = $date1;
date_add($date2, new DateInterval("P1M"));
echo "Date 1: ".date_format($date1, "Y-m-d")."<br/>";
echo "Date 2: ".date_format($date2, "Y-m-d")."<br/>";
?>
```

The result for this would be:

```
Date 1: 2014-05-05
Date 2: 2014-05-05
```

I was expecting the result of:

```
Date 1: 2014-04-05
Date 2: 2014-05-05
```

How can I get the expected result and fix this?
I can only use PHP, HTML and CSS so no jQuery or Javascript please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The `clone` keyword is what you need.

```
$date2 = clone $date1;
```

When an object is cloned, a shallow copy of all of the object's properties. Any properties that are references to other variables, will remain references.

If your object `$date2` holds a reference to another object `$date1` which it uses and when you replicate the parent object you want to create a new instance of this other object so that the replica has its own separate copy.

[`Source`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)

Answer (score 3):

This is due to how objects are assigned by reference since PHP 5; after assignment, changes made to one object are reflected in the other as well.

The generic solution is to clone the object:

```
$date2 = clone $date1;
```

In this case you could also use the [`DateTimeImmutable`](http://php.net/datetimeimmutable) interface (introduced in 5.5) which creates new instances whenever you attempt to modify it, e.g. using `->add()`.

```
$date1 = new DateTimeImmutable('2014-04-05');
$date2 = $date1;

$date2 = $date2->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));

echo "Date 1: ".date_format($date1, "Y-m-d")."<br/>";
echo "Date 2: ".date_format($date2, "Y-m-d")."<br/>";
```

This code can be made easier by doing this:

```
$date1 = new DateTimeImmutable('2014-04-05');
$date2 = $date1->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
```